# Multiple List to Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to convert multiple list into dictionary as in below output in python.

defined variables

```
a = ['23820', '29989']
i = ['hello', 'fdhcsl']
u = ['bye', 'cya']
```

Expected output: (nested dictionary)

```
nest = {'23820':{'i' : 'hello', 'u': 'bye' }, '29989':{'i': 'fdhcsl', 'u' : 'cya'}}
```

Is there is anyway this can by achieved by any means?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, mate?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Any code snippet ?

Comment: Hint: you can use `zip`.

Comment: i.e. `{aa: {'i': ii, 'u': uu} for aa, ii, uu in zip(a, i, u)}`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by the following code:

```py
a = ['23820', '29989']
i = ['hello', 'fdhcsl']
u = ['bye', 'cya']
nest = {}
for x,c in enumerate(a):
    nest.update({c:{'i':i[x],'u':u[x]}})
print(nest)
```

Comment: You can make this cleaner by using `zip` instead of `enumerate`, and a comprehension instead of a for-loop: `{c: {'i': d, 'u': e} for c, d, e in zip(a, i, u)}`